# How can I make this AJAX call work if you need to be authenticated?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to know how I can make AJAX calls to the Twitter API in order to get pictures of twitter users and display them back to the browser . The thing is that when I use the PHP method , it takes a VERY VERY LONG time to display profile pictures of a 100 twitter users generated by a loop .. So through this URL below that returns information about a twitter user, how could I use it with Jquery AJAX in order to fetch profile pictures images ?  This requires the call to be authenticated ..

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

Below is the PHP method I used , but it's SOO SLOW ..

```
 $id = $_GET['screen_name']; 
    * Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    foreach($id as $key  => $value) {
      $url = $connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => $value));
      $results  = json_encode($url);
      $data = json_decode($results, true);
      $image = '';  
      if(is_array($data)){  
       $image = $data['profile_image_url'];  ;
       $image_bigger = str_replace('_normal', '_bigger',$image); 
     }

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `users/lookup` endpoint which will let you pull 100 profiles at a time.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup

Note also that you cannot make pure ajax calls directly to the new Twitter API without exposing your secret keys to the public. You'll have to proxy these calls via your own back end.